# iPhone app for checking Railway PNR Status and Train Enquiry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ios4

I wanted to make an app through which we can check our Railway PNR Reservation status and if possible we can do railway Enquiry also but main part is PNR status.

Can anyone tell me how to start it? Does i have to implement any API's for that and if yes then which ones?

**UPDATED :-**

Actually i am viewing source codes of websites that how do they do it, there i found one link that gives the output in JSON...

```
 {'status': 'OK', 'data': {'passenger': [{'status': 'RAC   44', 'seat_number': 'W/L    8,RLGN'}], 'from': 'PUNE', 'alight': 'DMN', 'pnr_number': '8162588905', 'train_number': '*11039', 'to': 'DMN', 'board': 'PUNE', 'train_name': 'MAHARASHTRA EXP', 'travel_date': {'date': '1-12-2011', 'timestamp': 1322697600}, 'class': 'SL'}}
```

I dont know how to parse JSON as i know only NSXMLParser... I have followed many links but either i m not getting correct link or i am not understanding. can any one plz parse this and explain me.... I will be very thankful to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, please visit this [site](http://pnrapi.appspot.com/).

The call should be like http://pnrapi.appspot.com/8162588905

The response will be in JSON format.

**Edit:**

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{'status':....}";
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
id jsonObject = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:&error];
[jsonParser release]; jsonParser = nil;
if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
   NSDictionary *dict = jsonObject;
   NSString *status = [dict objectForKey:@"status"];
   NSDictionary *data = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
   NSArray *passengers = [data objectForKey:@"passenger"];

   //similarly do it for other members
}
```

**Edit #2:**

The site has been down and moved to another domain.

Now the call should be like http://pnrapi.alagu.net/api/v1.0/pnr/8166027281

For more info, pl. visit this [url](http://pnrapi.alagu.net/).

Comment: Hey Thanks A lot... means for this i have to learn JSON parsing as i know only NSXMLParsing.. :(   If there is no other way then i will use your answer and accept it...

Comment: try SBJson http://stig.github.com/json-framework/  Json parsing is actually easier to learn than XML parsing.

Comment: Go through [this link](http://jasarien.com/?p=428) to know little bit about json parsing using SBJson.

Comment: Aadhira.. thanks a lot for your responses and links.. but i am very sorry that i am not able to get it.. i m a big noob :( Can u plz help me in explaining how should i do it.. ;(

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Download SBJsonParser and include that in your project.

Comment: Wanted to know one more think the url u gave to me is giving in 'string' format but it should be in "string" format..?? (single quote and double quote) and thanks for the editing part.

Comment: That would not be a problem I guess. JSON parser will take care. If not, just replace all the single quotes with double quotes. That would be very easy.

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/ check here..... i have written here the response i get.. so it is telling me the error... but if we replace ' eith " it shows all correct.

Comment: Ok then go ahead by replacing single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: It did it..... and it is all beacuse of you..... Thanks a ton.... :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5260/discussion-between-mac-and-aadhira)

Comment: Hey!!! my app is Ready,Thanks to you... but it is only for PNR Status check, can i do anything more like train enquiry or train between two stations.... for that i think i need some API's or some urls...:P... So do you have any..???

Comment: Not working site ....its down can u plz give working link??

Comment: @PavanMore,  Try it with your valid PNR number

Comment: @Aadhira I have checked 2-3 times with valid PNR number but not getting the status . It showing {'status': 'TIMEOUT', 'data': 'Request Timed Out'} like this response.

Comment: @PavanMore, can you please post the PNR here?

Comment: @Aadhira Please check  http://pnrapi.appspot.com/8166027281

Comment: @PavanMore, I have updated my answer. Pl. check

Comment: @Aadhira Thanks a lot ....now working fine. Expecting the same co-operation in future.....!!! Thanks dude...:)

Comment: Glad that my answer really helps you.

Comment: @Aadhira Hi, do u know any other API's that can give me information regarding train schedule,their route,etc... Please share ur view regarding this.... waiting .... thanks...

Comment: Thanks Adhira... for helping my Friend. @Pavan :- She can't be dude as she sounds like a girl by name.

Answer (score 1):

here is another Api for getting pnr status in JSON format.
http://www.eyvaiinfotech.in/mobile/api.php?pnrno=2449943541

Comment: Do you know some more API's for checking seat availability or anything related to Railways ..?, it would be of great help.

Comment: there are no Apis available for that unless you develop them on your own.